# iOS static library load file from bundle INSIDE library

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static library that is supposed to load a json file and parse it. This is all done in the library itself, the json is not supposed to be visible / interactive for the target application.

In the library, the json is in the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase and therefore has a target membership to the library's target.

I am then trying to access the file via.

```swift
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "configs", ofType: "json")
```

but this always returns nil.

I have also tried the following:

```swift
Bundle(for: Self.self).path(forResource: "configs", ofType: "json")
Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "configs", withExtension: "json")
```

which also return nil.

The library is deployed via swift package manager, maybe i need to adapt the Package.swift file?

Comment: What happens if you write an actual case name, like`Bundle(for: MyClass.self)`? (this works for me)

Comment: @Yonat nil again... How is your file stored? Is it copied in build phases? How do you access it in the library? Thanks in advance.

Edit: When doing what you suggested, the loaded bundle is the bundle of the target app:
```NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E1D58F71-C0D0-480E-A4D3-0376AFC32CED/test.app>```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's be the static linking - it's all in the one bundle. I distribute an XCFramework, so it has it's own bundle.